# PHP Convert a string of comma separated values into another format without using a loop

Tags: php

In php, if I had a string of comma separated data like this which came from a database:

`John,Paul,Ringo,George`

how could I convert it to something like this, without using a for loop or any extra processing. Does php have a function that can do this?

```
$str = 'John','Paul','Ringo','George';
```

I currently split the string using explode and then reformat it. Anyway to achieve this without doing that?

The formatted string is sent to a SQL where it's used in a MySQL `IN()` function.

Comment: `$str = 'John','Paul','Ringo','George';` is wrong syntax

Comment: And the right one is?

Comment: `$str = "'John','Paul','Ringo','George'";` ?

Comment: Use the users ID for the mysql.

Comment: Ok. You mean it's wrong for php. But for MySQL it's right. I wont be echoing it in php, only sending it to the sql statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you absolutely don't want to use explode() you could use

```
$str = 'John,Paul,Ringo,George';
$newStr = "'" . str_replace(",","','", $str) . "'";
```

Comment: +1 for fastest solution. It's around 2x faster than implode/explode combination.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) with $1 thing.

**UPDATED:**
See usage example:

```
echo preg_replace('((\\w+)(,?))', '"$1"$2', 'John,Paul,Ringo,George');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use explode like below

```
$db_data = 'John,Paul,Ringo,George';//from your db
$l = explode(',',$db_data);
echo "select * from table where column IN('".implode("','",$l)."')";
```

***output***:

```
select * from table where column IN('John','Paul','Ringo','George')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) and [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) functions in PHP.

```
$names = explode(',', 'John,Paul,Ringo,George');
echo implode(',', $names);
```

Comment: I already do, but how do I get 'John', 'Paul' etc. I end up with 'John,Paul'

Comment: Your answer needs to be changed to `echo implode('\',\'', $names);` to get the formatting required.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got you right:

```
$str_1 = 'John,Paul,Ringo,George';
$str_2 = explode(',', $str_1);
$str_3 = implode('\',\'', $str_2);
$str_4 = '\''.$str_3.'\'';

echo $str_4;
```

Output: `'John','Paul','Ringo','George'`

Answer (score 1):

```
$l = 'John,Paul,Ringo,George';
$lx = "'" . implode("','", explode(",", $l)) . "'";
echo $lx; // 'John','Paul','Ringo','George'
```